# Matlab overlaying multiple surf/imagesc plots

Tags: image, matlab, merge

I have a set of multiple surf or imagesc plots, which have different colormaps, and I want the final plot to be the result of their merge: `surf_final = \sum_i surf_i`

The first hic, was the multiple color maps which was solved by following the [instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101346). There is no blending of the colors but rather a hard separation.

The desired result is rather the blending of the two colors and not a hard separation. One solution would be to convert each surf or imagesc to a matlab rgb images and just add them together: `rgb_f = rgb_1 + rgb_2, imshow(rgb_f)`.

The issue with such an approach is that the scale is lost, the various surfaces get re-scaled to the same dimension. One option would be to force the scaling to be consistent.

The ideal solution I am looking for would be a the blending of multiple surf plots whilst preserving scale and axis information, such other items can be easily plotted on top of the merged surfaces. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Result with merged colormap `cmap = [map1; map2]`:

[image]

Result by converting `Z1` and `Z2` of `surf1` and `surf2` to rgb
and then adding them:
[image]

(04-01-2014) I have made an example of the wanted solution, but only fo when one knows the probability density function of each surf to be plotted. For each surf, I have an individual `colormap`, `cmap_p1` and `cmap_p2`, for `pdf1` and `pdf2` respectively. I computed the likelihood on two meash grides `Z1` and `Z2`. I then computed a the mixing coefficients `alpha = Z1 ./ (Z1 + Z2)` and created an RBG Image as follows:

```
C1 = min(64,round((64-1)*(Z1-min(Z1(:))/(max(Z1(:))-min(Z1(:)))+1)
I(i,j,:) = alpha(i,j) * cmap_p1(C1(i,j),:) + (1 - alpha(i,j)) * cmap_p2(C2(i,j),:)
```

Comment: Could you show an image of what you are trying to make and what you have so far?

Comment: Hi, I would love to, however because of my reputation I cannot attach any image/figure to my question.

Comment: Perhaps you can upload the images somewhere and link to it? Someone with more rep can then include them in the post.

Comment: http://rapidshare.com/share/2FCBC9DF6D8D11A54F80A973562B7C0E, is downloadable link to the two related figures. The figure merge1.jpg is the result when using multiple colormaps as suggested in the url I gave. The figure imagefuse2.jpg is what happens when I convert the Z information to rgb and then add them together.

Comment: Have included the images that you linked. I am not sure how to approach this, perhaps blurring the resulting plot?

Comment: Hi Dennis, the second displayed plot is not exactly the required result. In the first plot you can see that the blue Gaussian function has a smaller density than the red. However when I transform both Z values to rgb I loose the scale information, that is why in the second plot the blue Gaussian function covers the same space as the red one.

Comment: One approach would computing the probability of a pixel belonging to one of the GMMs :  p(x|GMM=1) = p(x|GMM=1)/(p(x|GMM=1) + p(x|GMM=2)), which returns a value between 0 and 1. Then use this value for as a linear interpolation between the two colormaps. This would work in my case, but is not a general solution to merging two surf plots.

Comment: Why don't you work on the grayscale images? `imagesc` is scaling the colormap to span the full range of each individual data. So there is no consistency between the color of a given image and another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, if somebody has a level above 10 I would be greatfull if you could post density (1) and (2): link http://rapidshare.com/share/5E05B150DCBD4D50074452F68FDF13D3

My solution:

I have a set of density functions and associated colormaps {p(x),cmap}^N and a specified
meash grid X = Y = linspace(min,max,spacing).

1) In a loop I compute the CData_i for each pdf p_i(x)

2) I convert the CData to a RGB Image, I = reshape(cmap(CData(:),:),[spacing spacing 3] ) for each pdf_i

3) Compute mixing coefficients, f , for I based on CData (do his for each p_i(x):

```
 f(:,i) =  CData ./ max(CData(:)); (i is for the ith pdf)
 f = f./repmat(sum(f,2),1,number_pdfs);
```

The reason for this is that the final image will be a linear weighted combination of all the images, I_final = \sum_i f_i * I_i and \sum_i f_i = 1 should hold.

4) Final for loop which merges all the RGB images, Is = {I}, together

for i=1:nbGMMs

```
I = I + repmat(reshape(fractions(:,i),spacing,spacing),[1 1 3]) .* Is(:,:,:,i);
```

end

The **draw back is that all density functions must be evaluated on the same meashgrid** such that the pixel (x,y) coordinates correspond to the same column entries in the CData matrices.